# Downgrade working postgres cluster 10 to 9.x

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-10

Is there anyway to downgrade working postgres cluster 10 to 9.6? There are major changes (i.e, pg_wal / pg_xlog, etc.,) been done in 10. So far, I decided to take dump and restore into new 9.x cluster. Is there any other feasible way to do that?

Comment: Is your target 9.6 or some older version?

Comment: Actually, anything > 9

Comment: I'm not confident enough to answer the question. Just that 9.6 is different major version than 9.5, 9.4, etc. By the way, why do you want to downgrade? Did you encounter any specific issues while using version 10?

Comment: (I've also edited that 10.x to 10. The x is minor version for versions M.x where M>=10, so it's not very relevant.)

Comment: I'm not facing any critical issues though, but some app requirements. It really doesn't matter about minor version here. Just want to know that Is it really possible or not.